# Django 2.2: Creating models for multiple databases

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am new to Django 2.2 and I am building a small project that includes 2 databases not managed by Django. One is new and the other is legacy. I added them to the database list

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' :'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'petshows',
        'USER':'somecoolusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'somesecurepassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306'
    },
    'pets': {
        'ENGINE' :'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pets',
        'USER':'mysecureusers',
        'PASSWORD': 'somecoolpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306'
    }
}
```

I created models for petshows which seem to work fine. But I need to add some models so I can read foreign keys from the second database 'pets'.

```
My models.py

class ShowPets(models.Model):
    sp_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    pet_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    show_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'show_pets'


class Shows(models.Model):
    show_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=145, blank=True, null=True)
    show_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    location_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    org_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def show_date_pretty(self):
        return self.show_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shows'
```

I would like to create a model for Pets, pets table in the pets database, but I cannot figure out from the documentation how to be able to access the second database as a Model and then do a join on pet_id (foreign key), via the ShowPets model and the show_pets table (in the petshows database), to the pet_id (primary key) from pets table (in the pets database) to be able to pull things like pet_name, etc.

Can anyone give me any good hints or links on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django doesn't support `cross database joins` with the django orm.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations

But you can manually access either database using the [.using()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) method for querying:

```
Shows.objects.using('pets').all()
```

On save you can use the optional `using=` parameter to define the db to use:

```
show = Shows()
show.save(using='pets')
```

> As a side note, it's common practice to make your model names singular (then the above instance creation makes more sense)